# Proving that my algorithm works

Tags: solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices

I developed an algorithm to map eigenvectors onto a unique representation, removing the phase and dealing with degenerates. It works, but I don't know why. This is my algorithm:

Consider this matrix
$$
H =
\begin{pmatrix}
  1.6375816690258 & -0.4755832684370 & -0.0699416837860 \\
 -0.4755832684370 &  1.3547458407373 &  0.0521707197538 \\
 -0.0699416837860 &  0.0521707197538 &  1.0076724902369  
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If I diagonalize it I get the eigenvalues $[1,1,2] $ and depending on which numerical library I use, I get different eigenvectors matrices for the 1 eigenvalues:
$$
v1=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0.5839738582086 & -0.1462629956726 & -0.7984871126235 \\
  0.8016696443658 & -0.0507931153320 &  0.5956054404867 \\
 -0.1276726839671 & -0.9879408866586 &  0.0875927521938  
\end{pmatrix} \quad
v2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  0.6020119026848 &  0.0000000000000 & -0.7984871126235 \\
  0.7899898096965 & -0.1455000338086 &  0.5956054404867 \\
  0.1161799018825 &  0.9893582466234 &  0.0875927521938  
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The two column vectors are two different representations of the same space. In order to get them to a common representation I do the following:

1. Pick the top 2x2 submatrix and transpose it
   $$
   A1 = 
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0.5839738582086 & -0.1462629956726 \\
     0.8016696443658 & -0.0507931153320  
   \end{pmatrix} \quad 
   A2 = 
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0.6020119026848 &  0.0000000000000 \\
     0.7899898096965 & -0.1455000338086  
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
2. Perform QR-decomposition with the restriction, that the diagonal elements must be positive.

$$
A1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  0.5839738582086 & -0.1462629956726 \\
  0.8016696443658 & -0.0507931153320  
\end{pmatrix} =\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  0.9700370633940 &  0.2429569831099 \\
 -0.2429569831099 &  0.9700370633940  
\end{pmatrix}}_{Q1}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  0.6020119026848 &  0.7899898096965 \\
  0.0000000000000 &  0.1455000338086  
 \end{pmatrix}}_{R1}
$$
$$
A2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  0.6020119026848 &  0.0000000000000 \\
  0.7899898096965 & -0.1455000338086  
\end{pmatrix} =
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  1.0000000000000 &  0.0000000000000 \\
  0.0000000000000 & -1.0000000000000  
\end{pmatrix}}_{Q2}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  0.6020119026848 &  0.7899898096965 \\
  0.0000000000000 &  0.1455000338086  
\end{pmatrix}}_{R2}
$$

**This is the key part. R1 is always R2, but I don't know why.**

3. Apply unitary matrix to whole vector
   $$
   v1'= \\
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0.5839738582086 & -0.1462629956726 \\
     0.8016696443658 & -0.0507931153320 \\
    -0.1276726839671 & -0.9879408866586  
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0.9700370633940 &  0.2429569831099 \\
    -0.2429569831099 &  0.9700370633940  
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0.6020119026848 &  0.0000000000000 \\
     0.7899898096965 &  0.1455000338086 \\
     0.1161799018825 & -0.9893582466234  
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   $$
   v2' = \\
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0.6020119026848 &  0.0000000000000 \\
     0.7899898096965 & -0.1455000338086 \\
     0.1161799018825 &  0.9893582466234  
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     1.0000000000000 &  0.0000000000000 \\
     0.0000000000000 & -1.0000000000000  
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0.6020119026848 &  0.0000000000000 \\
     0.7899898096965 &  0.1455000338086 \\
     0.1161799018825 & -0.9893582466234  
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$

On the right hand site the top 2x2 matrix is just $R^T$. Since Q1 and Q2 are unitary matrices the norm should be conversed and v1' and v2' are still eigenvectors for the eigenvalues 1.

I have tested this algorithm extensively and I have never found a case where it doesn't work (within numerical inaccuracies).

How can I prove that R1 = R2?

If you want to play with the algorithm, then you can find it on github:
https://github.com/JuDFTteam/unique_eigenvectors

Comment: Are you specializing to symmetric matrices?

Comment: Yes it's either real symmetric or complex hermitian

Comment: I think you have some typos: $A_1 \ne Q_1R_1$, $A_2\ne Q_2R_2$ and $Q_1,Q_2$ are not unitary

Comment: Maybe this was due to low precision or some typo. I changed the example to use full precision.

Comment: I think you are essentially rotating the projection of the vectors in a 2D subspace hoping it always works. I'm guessing your algorithm works with high probability as long as the vectors $v1$ and $v2$ have a unique projection in the space formed by the first two rows. So for it to fail you might need something like $v1$ being an exact (or near) reflection of $v2$ in a plane with normal vector $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: The real algorthim is a little more compilcated: I take the first two rows, **that are linearly independent**. So if a row is 0 or if the first two are just linear dependent I might take the first and third. This doesn't explain why the QR-decompositions result in the same R.

Comment: @Stein There is some typos (doetoe also pointed out). It should be $A_1^T = Q_1 R_1$.

Answer (score 1):

**An explanation for this example**:

For convenience, I replace $v1, v2, A1, A2$ with $V_1, V_2, A_1, A_2$, respectively.

You perform QR to get $A_1^\mathsf{T} = Q_1R_1$ and $A_2^\mathsf{T} = Q_2 R_2$ with some restriction (positive diagonal entries).
You want to prove that $R_1 = R_2$.

Note that $V_1$ and $V_2$ have the same 3rd column (the eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $2$).
Denote the first two elements of the 3rd column of $V_1$ by $u$, i.e.
$$u = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 &-0.7984871126235 \\
 &0.5956054404867
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Using $V_1 V_1^\mathsf{T} = I_3$,
we have $A_1A_1^\mathsf{T} + uu^\mathsf{T} = I_2$. Using $V_2 V_2^\mathsf{T} = I_3$,
we have $A_2 A_2^\mathsf{T} + uu^\mathsf{T} = I_2$. Thus, we have $A_1 A_1^\mathsf{T}  = A_2 A_2^\mathsf{T}$.

Since $A_1^\mathsf{T} = Q_1R_1$ and $A_2^\mathsf{T} = Q_2 R_2$, we have
$R_1^\mathsf{T}R_1 = R_2^\mathsf{T}R_2$.

Let
$$R_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
 a_1 & b_1 \\
 0 & c_1  
\end{pmatrix},
\quad R_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
 a_2 & b_2 \\
 0 & c_2  
\end{pmatrix}.$$
From $R_1^\mathsf{T}R_1 = R_2^\mathsf{T}R_2$, we have
$$a_1^2 = a_2^2, \quad a_1b_1 = a_2b_2, \quad b_1^2 + c_1^2 = b_2^2 + c_2^2$$
which results in $R_1 = R_2$
(using $a_1, a_2, c_1, c_2 > 0$).